# Quartz cluster - load balancing doesn't work

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a problem with load-balancing Quartz jobs. When there are two instances running, only one of them handles all jobs. The second one is idling. When I terminate first instance the second one starts to handle jobs until first instance is started again.

I expected that there is kind of load-balancing which dispatches jobs between those two instances.

I am using Quartz version 1.8.6.

This is the part of applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="firstJobDetail"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.mycompany.quartz.job.FirstJob" />
    <property name="durability" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="firstTrigger" class="com.mycompany.quartz.PersistableCronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="firstJobDetail" />

    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/10 * * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean id="quartzScheduler"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">

    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/quartz.properties" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />

    <!-- This name is persisted as SCHED_NAME in db. for local testing could 
        change to unique name to avoid collision with dev server -->
    <property name="schedulerName" value="quartzScheduler" />

    <!-- Will update database cron triggers to what is in this jobs file on 
        each deploy. Replaces all previous trigger and job data that was in the database. 
        YMMV -->
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />

    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
    <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean class="com.mycompany.quartz.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory" />
    </property>

    <!-- NOTE: Must add both the jobDetail and trigger to the scheduler! -->
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="firstJobDetail" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="firstTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And this is the quartz.properties file:

```
# Spring uses LocalDataSourceJobStore extension of JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true

# Change this to match your DB vendor
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate

# Needed to manage cluster instances
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=MY_JOB_SCHEDULER

org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
```

Comment: Do you think that the problem is that I started both server processes on the same machine? It is not obvious but I think that the clock time has to be different.

Comment: Nay, if the clock time are different the one which has the "eldest" clock time will manage the jobs first.
Be careful with what you called "load balancing", Quartz start to load balance to another scheduler when the other scheduler is overloaded.
Is your first instance overloaded ?

Comment: I found that when there is more than one job, and jobs are more complex (something more thank log and sleep) it starts to load balance properly, even if I run instances on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you need to set `org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval` .

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. By the way, it is not required field since it has default value: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX

Comment: Did you check the database? Are there entries there? Do both instances point to the same database?

Comment: It is the same database, generally fail over works fine, because second instance works when the first one stops.

Answer (score 1):

I Know it is too late to answer your question. But recently I come across the same issue and found your post in online.

Whenever there are two instances running, either one of them tries to put lock on the job. Since your trigger time is every **10 secs** which is very less (0/10 * * * * ?), the instance 2 is unable to put lock on the job.

Increase the time period to one minute(* 0/1 * * * ?). You can see, both the instance will process the job.

Please let me know if you face any other issues.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html) says:

> Load-balancing occurs automatically, with each node of the cluster
>   firing jobs as quickly as it can. [...] Only one node will fire the
>   job for each firing. [...] It won’t necessarily be the same node each
>   time - it will more or less be random which node runs it. The load
>   balancing mechanism is near-random for busy schedulers (lots of
>   triggers) but favors the same node for non-busy (e.g. few triggers)
>   schedulers.